# How to clone a bios_grub partition?

Tags: grub2, dd, clone, boot-partition, clonezilla

I want to create a clone of my SSD. My partition table looks like this:

[image: Partition table screenshot]

However when using Clonezilla (which uses Partclone) in the `dd` mode, it fails to clone the first 1MB `bios_grub` partition (BIOS boot). When trying to make a clone in the "disk-to-image" mode, it also fails.

How to go about this? Alternatively, since I'm booting exclusively in UEFI mode, is it safe to simply delete this partition?

Comment: The bios_grub is only requried if booting in BIOS mode. ESP - efi system partition is only required if booting in UEFI mode. When first starting to use UEFI on new system, I would add both, but you only need one or the other. You also do not need a swap as large as you are showing. Ubuntu's default is a 2GB swap file. Many with servers still suggest a 4GB swap partition. But my desktop use never uses any swap.

Comment: If all you want to do is copy the bios_grub partition it should be possible using GParted. You will need some unallocated space on a backup drive (not unused filesystem space). It’s then a simple copy/paste operation